# If $\gamma$ is a closed path, then $\int_{\gamma}\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}dx+\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}dy\in2\pi\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

As the title says:
Let $\gamma$ be a smooth closed path that avoids $(0,0)$. I need to show that the line integral: $$\int_{\gamma}\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}dx+\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}dy$$ is a multiple of $2\pi$.
Note that $\gamma$ is allowed to self-intersect itself.

Intuitively this value should represent the "number of rotations around $(0,0)$", as they are counted with orientation, but this intuition is all I have.

Any ideas?

Comment: That's far from being short to prove.

Comment: For any closed path that does not intersect the result is $2\pi$, a closed self-intersecting path can be thought of as the union of closed paths that do no intersect.

Comment: Also should the curve avoid the origin?

Comment: Note that $$\oint_\gamma \left(\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}\,dx+\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\,dy\right)=\text{Im}\left(\oint_\gamma \frac1z\,dz\right)$$where $z=x+iy$.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla yes, it should, thank you

Comment: @MarkViola Nice. Is it well known that $\oint_\gamma \frac1z\,dz=2\pi i\nu(\gamma,0)$, where $\nu(\gamma,0)$ is the winding number (i.e., the number of times $\gamma$ completely circles the origin)?

Comment: @cyewaldman Hi Cye.  It is well known, but not necessarily taught until well after basic calculus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M = (0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R}$ and $\Phi : M \to \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus\{\mathbf{0}\}$ be the covering map $\Phi(r, \theta) = (r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$. Then we easily check that

$$ \omega = \frac{x dy - y dx}{x^2 + y^2} \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad \Phi^* \omega = d\theta $$

Now assume that $\gamma : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{\mathbf{0}\}$ is a smooth closed curve and let $\tilde{\gamma} : [0, 1] \to M$ be the lifting of $\gamma$, i.e., $\gamma = \Phi\circ\tilde{\gamma}$. Then $\tilde{\gamma}(1)$ and $\tilde{\gamma}(0)$ is mapped to the same point on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus\{\mathbf{0}\}$ and hence they differ by $(0, 2\pi n)$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. So

$$ \int_{\gamma} \omega = \int_{\tilde{\gamma}} \Phi^*\omega = \int_{\tilde{\gamma}} d\theta = 2\pi n. $$

Comment: That's the right answer, but it requires some deep results, namely the existence of a lifting, e.g.

Comment: I', sorry, what is $\Phi^*$?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I wrote this answer based on the assumption that OP's choice of 'differential-geometry' tag betrays his/her knowledge on basic facts of this area. But if my assumption turns out to be not true, you are completely right. We might need a workaround then.

Comment: @35T41, $\Phi^*\omega$ is the pullback of $\omega$. If you are not familiar to this concept, you can simply regard it as what you get when you apply the change of variables $(x, y) = \Phi(r, \theta)$ to $\omega$. As mentioned in my another comment, we may try some other elementary solution in case you are not aware of facts used in this answer.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, the differential geometry tag was a mistake. The only part I'm not famlilar with is the $\Phi^*\omega=d\theta$ notation, but apart from that I believe I understand the general idea

Comment: Although not being very difficult, I think that the mathematical language of this answer is a bit too heavy for the questioner.

Comment: Thanks to this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number I managed to understand your answer. Thank you for your willing to help.

Answer (score 7):

Take $\gamma : [0,1] \to \mathbb C$ a complex valued function, so that the quotient $\gamma'/\gamma$ is exactly what you obtain when replacing $\gamma$ into
$$\frac{dz}{z} = \frac{x-iy}{x^2+y^2}(dx+i dy)$$
and multiplying out. Thus, consider the function $h(t) = \int_0^t \frac{\gamma'(s)}{\gamma(s)}ds$. Set $H(t) =\gamma(t) \exp(-h(t))$, and observe that $H'(t) = 0$. This means $H(t)$ is constant, and then that $H(1) = H(0)$. All in all, we have $\gamma(1) \exp (-h(1)) = \gamma(0) \exp (-h(0))$
which gives that $\exp h(1) = 1$ or, what is the same, that $h(1) = 2\pi i n$ with $n\in \mathbb Z$.

*Remark*: this elementary argument is to be found in Apostol's *Mathematical Analysis*.

Comment: I really like this answer, would want to give more upvotes if I can. (+1)

Comment: Me too, and I've upvoted as well.

Answer (score 0):

We want to apply Green's Theorem but discontinuity at the origin poses a problem, we will avoid this.

I have drawn an arbitrary curve $c_1 \bigcup c_2$. Then I have added a circle that avoids the origin $c_4$. I have added a line connecting the arbitrary curve and the circle. We pass through this line twice, going in different directions so the effect of this line is nothing.

Together I call the curves $\sum$.

Integrating over $\sum$ is the same as integrating over $c_1 \bigcup c_2$ and $c_4$.

[image]

Integrating over $\sum$ gives zero by Greens Theorem. So it must be that,

$$0=\oint_{c_4}+\oint_{c_1 \bigcup c_2}=\oint_{\sum}$$

So,

$$\oint_{c_1 \bigcup c_2}=-\oint_{c_4}$$

Compute minus the integral over $c_4$, a circle of radius $r$, and we are done. Your result follows: If the curve $c$ intersect itself, divide it into closed non-self-intersecting curves $k_1,k_2,...k_n$. Then $\oint_{k_i}=\pm 2\pi$ with sign depending on orientation. The sum is thus in $2\pi\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Could you please try and make the image a bit smaller?

Answer (score -1):

Write $x=rsin(u), y=rsin(u)$, the form  $\alpha={{-y}\over{x^2+y^2}}dx+{{x}\over{x^2+y^2}}dy=du$ then take a circle $C$ contained in $\gamma$ and apply Stokes formula, since $d\alpha=0$, you obtain $\int_C\alpha=\int_{\gamma}\alpha=2\pi$.

Comment: It's definitely not that easy.  The integral may be zero as well, refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number for example.

Comment: This is a special case of what's to be proved.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe This reference very helped. Thank you